# How do I split a line from a file into a 2D list?

Tags: python, arrays, list, file, split

My file text.txt contains the following:

```
hello my
name is
jack black
and I
eat food
```

I'm trying to read this file into a 2D list called `arr` such that `arr[0][0] = hello` , `arr[0][1] = my`, and so on. I'm new to Python so I don't want to use numpy yet (I see that in a lot of similar questions).

Here is part of the code I have written so far:

```
for x in range(5):
    for y in range(2):
        nextLine = my_file.readline()
        nextLine = line.strip()
        arr[x][y]= [nextLine.split('\t')]
print(arr[0][0])
print(arr[0][1])
```

However, when I print `arr[0][0]` and `arr[0][1]`. I get the following:

```
[['hello my']]
[['name is']]
```

What is the best way to split 'hello' and 'my' such that each one enters the 2D list correctly in the same row?

Comment: You are splitting on tab characters (`'\t'`) but your strings use spaces.  Just do `arr[x] = nextLine.split()`.

Comment: Not sure how you initialized `arr` but you should really use the `append` method instead of assigning to an incremental index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use line counts.  Just read until the file is empty.  And `.strip` returns a list; you don't need to put it inside another list.

```
arr = []
for line in my_file:
    arr.append( nextLine.strip().split() )
print(arr[0][0])
print(arr[0][1])
```

Answer (score 0):

A file object produces lines when iterated over as a generator, so you can map the file object to the `str.split` method and construct a list with the resulting sequence:

```
arr = list(map(str.split, my_file))
```

Answer (score 0):

When we do

```
text=open("text.txt","r")
print(text.readlines())
```

We get the response

`['hello my\n', 'name is\n', 'jack black\n', 'and I\n', 'eat food']`

Since we are making a 2d array, our first index will be for the line and our second index will be for the specific word in the line.

````
text=open("text.txt","r")
wordArray=[]
allText=text.readlines()
for line in allText:
    lineArray=[]
    allWords=line.replace("\n","").split(" ")
    for word in allWords:
        lineArray.append(word)
    wordArray.append(lineArray)
print(wordArray)```

This will remove the \n's which cause a new line in the text file and then we split the words where there are spaces and append the words by line.
Hope this helps!
````

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("text.txt") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
arr = [l.strip().split(" ") for l in lines]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use pandas for reading the file and access the columns as arrays. Have a look into the pandas documentation for both operations:
[pd.read_csv()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#io-read-csv-table) and [df columns](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html)

```
df = pd.read_csv('input.txt', sep=" ", header=None, names=["a", "b"])
df["a"]  # This is your array
```